# Why is the Replace function is not working in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Replace function is not working in xslt 2.0

xslt looks like this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version='2.0'
xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
xmlns:fn='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-funcations'>

    <xsl:output
           method="xml"
           encoding="utf-8"
           media-type="application/xml"
      />
      <xsl:template match='/'>

        <items>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="response/result/doc"/>
        </items>

      </xsl:template>

      <!-- search results xslt -->
      <xsl:template match="doc">

    <xsl:variable name="ShortDescription" select="str[@name = 'ShortDescription']"/>

    <shortdescription><xsl:value-of select="replace($ShortDescription, '&amp;amp;', '&amp;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></shortdescription>

    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When we use replace function we get this error:

[image]

and i am checking **replace** function on online xslt tester and some tool are given error and some are not why this?

```
www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.U-inrWNknIU   ==> given error
http://www.xsltcake.com/                                    ==> given error
http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php  ==> given error
http://xslttest.appspot.com/                                ==> not given error.its working fine.
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog ==> given error
```

and i am using solr 4.0 ,xslt 2.0 and xml 1.0

Please give me an idea of how to handle this **replace** function in xslt 2.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an attempt to consolidate doubly escaped ampersands? In that case you need to escape `&amp;` once again: `replace($ShortDescription, '&amp;amp;amp;', '&amp;amp;')`

Comment: i had check with doubly escaped ampersands but its not working. and my question is why replace function not working in my xslt 2.0 with firefox and chrome.

Comment: I suspect the reason is that you aren't using an XSLT 2.0 processor. I don't know how you configure the choice of XSLT 2.0 processor for solr 4.0, but just putting version="2.0" in the stylesheet is probably not enough.

Comment: thank you for your response. what should i do more to define xslt version 2.0 and to use replace function?

Answer (score 2):

> www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.U-inrWNknIU   ==> given error

That tool uses XSLT 1.0 (javax.xml.transform)

> http://www.xsltcake.com/                                    ==> given error

That tool uses XSLT 1.0 (browser version, i.e. Transformiix in Firefox)

> http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php  ==> given error

That tool uses XSLT 1.0 (libxsl)

> http://xslttest.appspot.com/                                ==> not given error.its working fine.

That tool uses XSLT 2.0 (SAXON 9.3.0.5 from Saxonica)

> http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog ==> given error

That tool uses XSLT 1.0 (browser version, i.e. Transformiix in Firefox)

As others have already commented, the function `fn:replace` is a function added in XSLT 2.0 (actually, XPath 2.0, which is part of XSLT 2.0). Run your stylesheet with a 2.0 processor (like [Saxon](http://saxonica.com), [Exselt](http://exselt.net) or [Altova](http://www.altova.com/solutions/xslt.html)) and you should be fine. How to configure it for your product depends on whether it supports using / plugging in a different processor.

Note: the namespace you use for `fn` is wrong. You do not need to specify that namespace (it's implicit), but if you do, use `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`.